# Suddenly showing Invalid Scopes: openid error to live users who try to login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

My app provides a Facebook page scheduling feature. so, we are asking for the below permission while the user tries to log in with our app.
permission: `email`, `public_profile`, `pages_show_list`, `pages_manage_list`
Live users are already using this feature.

Now we are developing scheduling for a group also. but it is under development & permission review status is IN DRAFT.

I have searched a lot and many developers have suggested adding Facebook Login For Business as a Product. but it not working.

Please help to resolve this critical issue. As many live users are facing this issue.